# Phonegap app communicate with php server without using ip address

Tags: javascript, php, android, cordova, networking

Question:
How can I get a phonegap application (using ajax) to communicate with a php server inside a local network without knowing the server's IP address?

I tried using the hostname as the URL (http://hostname/) and it works on my computer's browser but it doesn't work on android or in my application.

Right now, the server has a static IP address but I would like for the application to work with a server that has a dynamic IP address instead.

I came across a couple of questions on here that were similar except they required connecting to an external server (http://jsonip.appspot.com/) and they returned the IP address given by the service provider.  I am looking for something to run in a local network to give the IP address assigned by the router.

The only other thing I could think of was sending a UDP broadcast which, from what I've read, is hard to do if not impossible.

Would anyone be able to provide some more input or options?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: "http://home-server/application.php",
    data: {username: $("#username").val(), password: $("password").val()}
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == "approved") {
            //redirect user to home page
        } else if (data == "invalid") {
            //clear form
        }
    },
    error: function(x, exception) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

The url works on my computer but android/phonegap can't resolve the url. I read up on the access element and my understanding of it led me to try the following  without luck:

```
<access origin="http://home-server/" />
<access origin="http://home-server/application.php" />
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: you can use ip address of server insted of host name

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define the IP address, you can use the domain  without problems. Is posible you have not access to connect to with the  server.

Try add on your config.xml:

```
<access origin="http://yourdomain.com" />
```

Or:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: I'm wanna make sure I'm adding the element correctly.  The IP address of my server is 192.168.0.9 and the hostname of the device is home-server.  On my computer I can access the server using http://home-server/application.php and ajax works fine.  So in my app I should add <access origin="http://home-server" /> and in ajax should I keep the url as "http://home-server/application.php" or can I just use "application.php"?

Comment: In your case, you need to use the IP address, you can to access as "home-server" from your PC because you are using some service for hostname resolution. The emulator is a virtual machine with his own operative system and do not uses the same services. If you need to configure a static IP address, you can force it from your connection options, or configurating the DHCP server for static address asigment by hmac address.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I kind of assumed I wasn't going to be able to do what I wanted to do but was hoping there was something out there that I didn't know about yet.  Thank you for your assistance.